# Can I make gdb/ddd quickly skip over to the beginning of an infinite recursion error?

Tags: debugging, recursion, gdb, segmentation-fault

If I have an infinite recursion bug, when I discover this in `ddd`, it takes a long time to produce a backtrace from the segfault.

If `a`, `b,`, `c,`, etc are functions and the call stack is

```
 a b c c c c ... (thousands) ... c c (SIGSEGV)
```

or

```
 a b c b c ... (thousands) ... b c b c (SIGSEGV)
```

It can take a couple of minutes to produce the associated stack trace.

If I suspect this is the case, is there a way I can tell gdb/ddd to quickly skip to the beginning of the repetitions instead of waiting for it to trace all the way back up?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to print full backtrace in case of infinite recursion. You need only a [few outermost frames](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html) to understand the cause of infinite recursion. For example you can print 10 outermost frames with the command:

```
(gdb) bt -10
```

Exact number of frames to print may vary and depends on where infinite recursion begins.